# Regex: Concatenate/connect the letters in words separated by space in html tag

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this html tag:

`<title>c o n n e c t s  t h e  l e t t e r s  i n  w o r d s</title>`

**Must Become:**

`<title>connects the letters in words</title>`

I try this, but doesn't work:

FIND: `(<title>)(.+?\s+.+?)(</title>)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\2\3`

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to do that with regex, at least not in a single statement. perhaps you can find all the double-spaces, replace them with a delimiter character, then replace all spaces, and finally replace the delimiter with a single space.

Comment: it is simple fo find empty spaces `(\s+)` . The problem is how I replace. I am sure @Toto will find the answer tomorrow

Comment: right, but you have only one capture group, and many spaces. and you want to preserve the one of the spaces when they are doubled. you would need as many capture groups as there are spaces to replace. right now your example pattern would only capture the characters 'c o n', and leave the spaces in it, since they are part of your capture group. the rest of the inner string would be ignored. you'd have more options if you were not trying to preserve the title tags, but since you need them, its hard to deal with the multiplicity.

Comment: I think I just find half of formula: FIND `(\w)(\x20)`  and REPLACE BY: `\1`  Must just put it in <titlte> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<title>|\G)\S*\K(?:\h+(\h)|\h+)(?=.*</title>)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    <title>     # literally, open tag
  |           # OR 
    \G          # restart from last match position
)           # end group
\S*         # 0 or more non space
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
(?:         # non capture group
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal space
    (\h)        # group 1, 1 horizontal space
  |           # OR
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal space
)           # end group
(?=         # positive lookahead, make sure we have, after:
    .*          # 0 or more any character
    </title>    # literally, close tag
)           # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: I knew that only @Toto will find the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: by the way, what is the difference between `\G` and `\K` ?

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu: You'll find better explanation than I can give [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) and [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)